# Oracle Apex Custom Row in a report

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5.1

[image: Apex]

How make this type of report where, I can show the total sum of a column, in Oracle Apex

Comment: The image is attached.

Answer (score 1):

That looks like a **classic report**. Navigate to column's properties and set **compute sum** to "Yes" (under the *Advanced* properties section).

Comment: How can I generate an Invoice after submitting a form?

Comment: To print it? I use Oracle Reports 10g to create *reports* and submit it to Oracle 10g IAS which creates a PDF document. Alternatively, some time ago I used Jasper Reports with Apache Tomcat.

Comment: I don't know how to use this, by the way, in php we can pass value to a different page after submitting by $_POST, is this possible in APEX? I mean if I submit a form, at the same time it will be updated in database and also show the submitted values in a different page?

Comment: Submit can/will store a value into the database; another page's item can have - as a source - value from any other page.

Comment: If i want to do without storing in database, suppose submitted a form which contains a value and I want to display the value in a redirected page after submitting.